# How to i18n form errors with spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, error-messaging

So I can't make these default messages change to the ones I want. In all the JSP files they work great, but I can't make them work inside a form.

Here is my UserController:

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/user/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView userProfilePost(@ModelAttribute("userForm") @Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return userProfileGet(userForm);
        }
        User user = us.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        user = userHelper.update(userForm, us ,user);
        userForm = new UserForm();
        userForm.setName(user.getName());
        userForm.setEmail(user.getEmail());
       return userProfileGet(userForm);
    }
```

Then we have my WebConfig:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource()
    {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:languages_i18n/messages", "classpath:languages_i18n/validation");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

My UserForm:

```
public class UserForm {
    @Email()
    private String email;
    @Size(max=100 , min=3)
    private String password;
    @Size(max=100 , min =3)
    private String name;

    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Here I tried also doing (which didn't work of course haha):

```
    @Email(message = "{Email.UserForm.email}")
    private String email;
    @Size(max=100 , min=3, message = "{Size.UserForm.password}")
    private String password;
    @Size(max=100 , min =3, message = "{Size.UserForm.name}")
    private String name;
```

Here is my validation_en.properties:

```
Email.UserForm.email = Your e-mail format is not valid
Size.UserForm.password = Your password must have between {min} and {max} characters
Size.UserForm.name = Your name must have between {min} and {max} characters
```

I know that when I do it right, the lines in the .properties file should get colored but they are still grey, so clearly I am not reaching them correctly.
Any comment will be well received, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution was that the first letter of the form should be lower case, like this (I do not know why):

```
Size.userForm.password = Your password must have between {2} and {1} characters
Size.userForm.name = Your name must have between {2} and {1} characters
```

After that we have to add what Tung Phan said that was also correct because parameters are object array, so {min} and {max} were wrong.

Hope this is useful for anyone in the future.

Comment: From what I've seen it should be `userForm` because it is the "object name", not the Java class name, in your case the "object name" was set here: `@ModelAttribute("userForm")`

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are an Object array.

The {0} is field name, other fields are in alphabatical order, max and then min.

So it should be:

```
Size.UserForm.password = Your password must have between {2} and {1} characters
Size.UserForm.name = Your name must have between {2} and {1} characters
```

Comment: Ill make that change, thank you. Anyway the problem is before that, the form can't reach the error message so it sends a default message.